# iTextSharp: Header on only First Page

Tags: asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp for a project in ASP.NET.
I have generated what I want so far.

**The Issue**
1. I want the HEADER to be displayed ONLY on First Page of my PDF. But, the Header content appears on every new page generated.

2. Also, The table being generated has to have 60 rows on first page and about 65 rows on all other pages (since the header will not be there).

**Code so Far:**

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
Phrase phrase = null;
PdfPCell cell = null;
Color color = null;
pdfDoc.Open();

int columns = grdGridPrint.Columns.Count;
// Table and PdfTable classes removed in version 5.XXX
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columns);
// table.TotalWidth = 500f;

// Draw first-page-only header
//ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.DirectContent);
//XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(new ColumnTextElementHandler(ct), new StringReader(html));
//ct.SetSimpleColumn(document.Left, document.Top, document.Right, document.GetTop(-PDFMarginTop), 0, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
//ct.Go();

phrase = new Phrase();

phrase.Add(new Chunk("Elam Fataka\u00AE \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("Mahakali Complex, Tarsa Road,Kanhan \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("Proprietor : Liladhar Barve, ", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("(M) 9326560090 | (O) 07102-236297  \n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("All Agent List - Total Agent :" + grdGridPrint.Rows.Count.ToString() + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("Printing Date : " + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));
phrase.Add(new Chunk("\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 7, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)));

cell = ClsPDF.PhraseCell(phrase, PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.VerticalAlignment = PdfCell.CHUNK;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a paragraph on the first page.

```
pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("This Is My Header"));
```

Your rows will automatically spill over to the next page as needed.

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that (+1 from me). If this doesn't answer the question, then the question is probably wrong. Also: why do you think @GenXCoders is using an old version of iText? We don't call it iTextSharp anymore; we call it iText for .NET. And classes such as `ColumnText` and `PdfPCell` don't exist anymore in iText 7. Looking at the code, it's written by a newbie, and I wonder: why would someone who is new to iText, start working with an old version instead of with the latest version?